# How to place others name object to last position of the array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a object of array  which is give below -

```
arrayData = [
{label:"data",value:"data"},
{label:"data",value:"data"},
{label:"Others",value:"Others"},
{label:"data",value:"data"},
]
```

and want to shift the **others** object at the last position of the array and i also don't know the index value of that object.

Thankyou

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift

Answer (score 0):

You can filter it out first and push then into the end:

```js
var arrayData = [
  {label:"data",value:"data"},
  {label:"data",value:"data"},
  {label:"Others",value:"Others"},
  {label:"data",value:"data"},
]

var res = arrayData.filter(x => x.label !== 'Others');
res.push(arrayData.find(x => x.label === 'Others'));
    
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get the index first, splice this item and push the spreaded array.

```js
var array = [{ label: "data", value: "data" }, { label: "data", value: "data" }, { label: "Others", value: "Others" }, { label: "data", value: "data" }],
    index = array.findIndex(({ value }) => value === 'Others');
    
array.push(...array.splice(index, 1));

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

> i also don't know the index value of that object

for that you can use [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex). First get the index of the required object , and in another variable get the last object in the array. Then swap their place

```js
var arrayData = [{
    label: "data",
    value: "data"
  },
  {
    label: "data",
    value: "data"
  },
  {
    label: "Others",
    value: "Others"
  },
  {
    label: "data",
    value: "data"
  },
]

let findIndex = arrayData.findIndex(function(item) {
  return item.label === 'Others' && item.value === 'Others'
})
let storeLastVal = arrayData[arrayData.length - 1];
let otherVal = arrayData[findIndex]
arrayData[findIndex] = storeLastVal;
arrayData[arrayData.length - 1] = otherVal;
console.log(arrayData)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can first parse the array and create two arrays, one with the elements that will stay in place, the other with the elements that will be placed at the end. Then you can join those 2 arrays.

```
arrayData = [
{label:"data",value:"data"},
{label:"data",value:"data"},
{label:"Others",value:"Others"},
{label:"data",value:"data"},
]

var startValues = [];
var endValues = [];

arrayData.forEach((value) => {
  if (value.label === "Others") {
    endValues.push(value);
  } else {
    startValues.push(value);
  }
});

arrayData = startValues.concat(endValues);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use recursion. This program has a distinct advantage in that it doesn't have to find the element (or index) before beginning the computation -

```js
const data =
  [ { label: "data", value: "data" }
  , { label: "data", value: "data" }
  , { label: "Others", value: "Others" }
  , { label: "data", value: "data" }
  ]
  
const transform = ([ a, ...rest ]) =>
  a === undefined
    ? []
    : a.label === "Others"
        ? [ ...transform (rest), a ]
        : [ a, ...transform (rest) ]

console .log (transform(data))
// [ { label: "data", value: "data" }
// , { label: "data", value: "data" }
// , { label: "data", value: "data" }
// , { label: "Others", value: "Others" }
// ]
```

Obviously you should probably make `"Others"` a parameter of the function -

```js
const data =
  [ { label: "data", value: "data" }
  , { label: "data", value: "data" }
  , { label: "Others", value: "Others" }
  , { label: "data", value: "data" }
  ]
  
const transform = (query, [ a, ...rest ]) =>
  a === undefined
    ? []
    : a.label === query
        ? [ ...transform (query, rest), a ]
        : [ a, ...transform (query, rest) ]

console .log (transform ("Others", data))
// [ { label: "data", value: "data" }
// , { label: "data", value: "data" }
// , { label: "data", value: "data" }
// , { label: "Others", value: "Others" }
// ]

console .log (transform ("data", data))
// [ { label: "Others", value: "Others" }
// , { label: "data", value: "data" }
// , { label: "data", value: "data" }
// , { label: "data", value: "data" }
// ]
```

Note, the original input is *not* mutated. If multiple labels are found matching the query, *all* of them will be moved to the end of the array.